# Move existing project to new location

Tags: c#, .net, reference, visual-studio-2019, projects-and-solutions

In one solution I have 5 projects. One is in location that I want it to be, and 4 are on Desktop. After I move 4 to desired location all my references are with yellow triangle.

I cant find where I can change path of references to new location. Please help me.

I am using Visual Studio 2019 and Windows 10.

[image: On desired location]

[image: On Desktop]

Comment: please check the csproj file and check the hintpath of the Reference dll. The hintpath use the relative path, if your project location changes, so the hintpath also needs to be changed, please modify it according to your project and let it find your current DLL.

Answer (score 0):

You could edit as well the [solution file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/internals/solution-dot-sln-file?view=vs-2019) (*.sln)

Example:

```
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Project1", "Path1\Project1.csproj", "{AB7E62D6-5830-49A3-9B1D-A2B3CEF7AFFE}"
EndProject
Project("{FAE04EC0-301F-11D3-BF4B-00C04F79EFBC}") = "Project2", "Path2\Project2.csproj", "{B060AA30-2CD8-4670-8446-3CD999C0A1AC}"
EndProject
```

Answer (score 0):

Dosen't work. Change the path and still the same, unload, also the same.